# Open a new form from another form from another form

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have created a welcome form that if you want can open a new form, and so far is everything ok, but all the problems come when I want to open another form from the new one ( one form from a new form from a new form, like inception).
is constantly giving me an error as soon as I try to open the third form, but I can't understand why.

This is the main form,I click on "crea un nuovo progetto" to create a new project
[image]

Here is the new form:
[image]

Here I click on "visualizza grafici" for see the graph.

and here are the code for open the first form:

```
Nuovo_progetto f2 = new Nuovo_progetto();
        f2.ShowDialog();
```

And here for open the second:

```
Grafico grafico = new Grafico();

        grafico.ShowDialog();// error:System.InvalidOperationException
```

I don't know what to do, I tried every tutorial but is always giving me an error.

if you know something pls help me

Comment: Please provide more details about the error - error message, inner exception, stack trace and so on. From information you provided it is impossible to say much about the problem.

Comment: You might need to debug code of `Grafico` form. Specially the load event of it

Comment: @Chetan it was a function that i put in the load event, I am so dumb, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Open the first form as a non-modal dialog
Nuovo_progetto f2 = new Nuovo_progetto();
f2.Show();

if (f2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) // Check the dialog result of the first form (e.g., OK button clicked)
{
    // If a specific condition is met, open the second form
    Grafico grafico = new Grafico();
    grafico.Show();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).